# Zendesk Audit Logs API date filter not working

Tags: curl, httprequest, zendesk, zendesk-api

I have been using Zendesk APi's for quite sometime and noticed that date filters for Audit Logs APi (https://developer.zendesk.com/api-reference/ticketing/account-configuration/audit_logs/) doesn't work right.

I have tried both curl and https requests via Python, somehow doesn't limit the results

curl "https://domain.zendesk.com/api/v2/audit_logs.json?filter[created_at]=1692282990&filter[sort_order]=asc" -H "Authorization: Bearer xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"

curl " https://domain.zendesk.com/api/v2/audit_logs.json?created_at=2023-08-18T06:47:00Z -H "Authorization: Bearer xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"

I have tried the above and not works, helppp !!